# Please replace "above" with "below" in the Controversial Post Notice

Tags: bug, status-completed, wording, post-notices

Currently, the text of Controversial Post Notice says,

> **Controversial Post —** You may use comments ONLY to suggest improvements. You may use answers ONLY to provide a solution to the specific question asked **above**. Moderators will remove debates, arguments or opinions **without notice**.

This text was accurate when the post notices were added below the question.

But now their position is changed, can we replace "above" with "below"?

Comment: I would consider using position-agnostic term like "here" instead of above/below

Comment: Or... just delete "above", i.e., "...the specific question asked."

Comment: Even better: "...to provide a solution to the question."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed on Interpersonal Skills, Philosophy, The Workplace, and Academia, the four communities that it appears on.

I just used "below" because it was the minimum change, but this is a custom reason that lives in the per-site databases so if the community agrees on a non-directional language, it's relatively simple to change again.